# How do I find out what is stopping a sit tunnel routing?

Tags: networking, fedora, nmcli, tunneling

In my town, IPv6 does not exist with any provider. I own 2001:67c:2284::/48 which I announce with Vultr.

I am trying to set up a SIT tunnel to use 2001:67c:2284:1::/64 from my office using nmcli but I'm not having much look.

The server is a Fedora 38 minimal install running nothing but bird2 and firewalld.

Bird has established it's connection with Vultr properly.

To protect my ipv4 office ip address i have replaced it with ###.###.###.### and server ip with SSS.SSS.SSS.SSS i will just null route the /64 prefix and change the one I use once I get it working.

on the server I have run:

```
nmcli con add type 'ip-tunnel' con-name 'sit1' ifname 'sit1' mode 'sit' remote '###.###.###.###' -- ipv4.method 'disabled' ipv6.method 'manual' ipv6.address '2001:67c:2284:1::1' ip-tunnel.ttl 64
```

on my laptop (also fedora 38):

```
nmcli con add type 'ip-tunnel' con-name 'sit1' ifname 'sit1' mode 'sit' remote 'SSS.SSS.SSS.SSS' local '###.###.###.###' -- ipv4.method 'disabled' ipv6.method 'manual' ipv6.address '2001:67c:2284:1::2' ipv6.gateway '2001:67c:2284:1::1' ip-tunnel.ttl 64
```

using ping6 or mtr i get a response from the IP on both machines but when I try to run either on the remote ipv6 address ping shows destination unreachable and mtr shows no route to host.

running `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding` returns 1 on the server so IPV6 forwarding is enabled.

ip -6 r outputs the following:

server: `2001:67c:2284:1::1 dev sit1 proto kernel metric 675 pref medium`
laptop: `2001:67c:2284:1::1 dev sit1 proto static metric 675 pref medium`
`2001:67c:2284:1::2 dev sit1 proto kernel metric 675 pref medium`
`default via 2001:67c:2284:1::1 dev sit1 proto static metric 675 pref medium`

For testing I enabled DMZ on my router to prevent nat issues but that hasn't solved it.

Any pointers would be greatly apreciated.